# Excluding Measurements based on Drug adminstration

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am performing a data analysis on a vast medical dataset. I am trying to wrap my head around the following issue. The task is to include only protein measurements that were taken before the administration of the drug (where drug == 1).

Representative dataset:

```
dataset <- structure(
            list(
Participant.Id = 1:5,

HR_date_1 = as.Date(c("15-06-2013", "02-03-2013", "20-10-2012", "07-08-2015", "03-09-2014"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
HR_date_2 = as.Date(c("15-06-2014", "02-03-2014", "20-10-2013", "07-08-2016", "05-06-2017"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
HR_date_3 = as.Date(c("15-06-2017", "21-06-2015", NA, "17-03-2017", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
HR_date_4 = as.Date(c("15-06-2018", "02-03-2016", NA, "07-08-2018", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
HR_date_5 = as.Date(c(NA, "02-03-2019", NA, "07-08-2021", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
HR_date_6 = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),

HR_value_1 = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L),
HR_value_2 = c(15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L),
HR_value_3 = c(20L, 25L, NA, 45L, NA),
HR_value_4 = c(25L, 30L, NA, 50L, NA),
HR_value_5 = c(NA, 35L, NA, 55L, NA),
HR__value_6 = c(NA, 35L, NA, NA, NA),

trial_participation = as.Date(c("16-06-2014", NA, "10-06-2015", "30-07-2016", "10-08-2018"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
drug =                c("1", "0", "1", "0", "0"),

                       
protein_date_1 = as.Date(c("25-06-2011", "10-03-2013", "20-10-2013", "07-08-2014", "15-09-2014"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
protein_date_2 = as.Date(c("16-06-2013", "21-03-2014", "05-03-2017", "07-08-2015", "03-06-2017"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
protein_date_3 = as.Date(c("16-06-2014", "10-06-2015", NA, "30-07-2016", "10-08-2018"), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
protein_date_4 = as.Date(c("15-06-2018", "05-04-2016", NA, "07-08-2018", NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
protein_date_5 = as.Date(c(NA, "02-03-2019", NA, NA, NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
protein_date_6 = as.Date(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), format = "%d-%m-%Y"),

protein_A_1 = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 400L, 500L),
protein_A_2 = c(110L, 210L, 310L, 410L, 510L),
protein_A_3 = c(120L, 220L, NA, 420L, 520L),
protein_A_4 = c(130L, 230L, NA, 430L, NA),
protein_A_5 = c(NA, 240L, NA, NA, NA),
protein_A_6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
 
protein_B_1 = c(101L, 201L, 301L, 401L, 501L),
protein_B_1 = c(111L, 211L, 311L, 411L, 511L),
protein_B_1 = c(121L, 221L, NA, 421L, 521L),
protein_B_1 = c(131L, 231L, NA, 431L, NA),
protein_B_1 = c(NA, 241L, NA, NA, NA),
protein_B_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),

protein_C_1 = c(102L, 202L, 302L, 402L, 502L),
protein_C_1 = c(112L, 212L, 312L, 412L, 512L),
protein_C_1 = c(122L, 222L, NA, 422L, 522L),
protein_C_1 = c(132L, 232L, NA, 432L, NA),
protein_C_1 = c(NA, 242L, NA, NA, NA),
protein_C_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
```

class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -5L)
)

For participants where drug == 1, I want to check if any protein measurements were taken on or after the trial participation date. If a protein measurement date matches or comes after the trial participation date, those specific protein measurements (for Id one for example A4-6, B4-6, C4-6) for that participant should not be included in the final dataset.

What I want to do is to

1. Identify participants where drug == 1.
2. For these participants, compare the trial participation date with the protein measurement dates.
3. Exclude the correlating protein measurements that were taken on or after the trial participation date for each participant where drug == 1. (For example if drug ==1 and trial date is 01-01-2020, I want the code to check for each participant if the date is == or >= and if this is for example date_3, exclude protein_A_3-6, protein_B_3-6, and protein_C_3-6)
4. I do want to include all data for participants where drug == 0.

I would love to hear your thoughts! If my question is not clear please tell me nd I will try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you pivot your data to long format. Here’s a tidyverse solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataset <- dataset %>%
  pivot_longer(
    !c(Participant.Id, trial_participation, drug),
    names_to = c(".value", "time"),
    names_pattern = "(.+)_([^_]$)"
  ) %>%
  mutate(across(
    protein_A:protein_C,
    \(x) if_else(drug == 1 & protein_date >= trial_participation, NA, x)
  ))
```

From here, you could pivot back to wide format if needed for your analysis, but otherwise I would keep it as long. If you do need to pivot back to wide:

```r
dataset <- dataset %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = time,
    values_from = HR_date:protein_C
  )
```